# yii2 session timeout not working

Tags: php, session, yii2

```
 'session' => [
        'name' => 'test',
        'timeout' => 20,
    ],
```

I have set session timeout to be 20 second in my configuration. But session is still active after 20 second.

Answer (score 0):

You can set property `authTimeout` in `user` component:

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass'   => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout'     => 20
],
```